Why are log lines missing without a flush?
I have a simple class in C++20 that logs data to a file line by line for Windows platform. To ensure thread safety, I use a static std::mutex to serialize the write operations.
However, I encounter an issue: if I don't explicitly call flush after each write while holding the lock, some lines are missing in the output file. When I call flush, all lines are correctly written to the file.
Here’s a simplified version of the code:
class Logger {
public:
    void Log(const std::string& message) {
        std::lock_guard lock(mtx_);
        log_file_ << std::format("{}\n", message);
        // log_file.flush(); // Uncommenting this works fine
    }

private:
    static std::mutex mtx_;
    std::ofstream log_file_{ "log.txt", std::ios::app };
};

std::mutex Logger::mtx_;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::future<void>> futures;

    // Launch the function asynchronously
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, []() { 
            Logger logger;
            logger.Log("Test message"); }));
    }

    // Wait for all tasks to complete
    for (auto& future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }
}

Why does this happen? Why doesn't the operating system automatically handle flushing the output when it's serialized using a mutex, without explicitly calling flush?
Is this expected behavior for file streams in C++?

I assume that there isn't any issue related to the mutex because I didn't see any overlapped log instances on the file. So my question is actually isn't about thread safety.

If you don't flush you have no idea when the OS will actually commit the data to the backing file. That's why flush exists; to force the OS to commit buffered writes.

If writing to a file then (by default) buffers are not flushed.   If the flushing is not serialised along with the content being written (i.e. before releasing the mutex) then the clearing of buffers and (physically) writing to the file are not serialised relative to writes on other threads.   That causes undefined behaviour.

The mutex makes guarantees about memory in the same process. It says nothing about side effects beyond that; in this case, it has no effect like triggering a call to flush() or waiting for the completion of operating system calls.

"Why doesn't the operating system automatically handle flushing" -- Technically, flushing is handled automatically, since otherwise there would be no data in the file. Your question is more "Why does the automatic flushing not occur while the mutex is locked?"

ofstream is typically line-buffered and flushes automatically on \n. flush exists for handling streams that are not line-buffered, or when you want manual flushing. In any case, your log_file_ is not static so you are repeatedly opening and closing the file outside of your lock.

"Is this expected behavior for file streams in C++?" - Yes.

At least you provide a [mre] - +1 for that (although you are missing some includes).

There is no synchronisation between the buffers of the streams. The buffer will be flushed when the stream is closed. This will, most likely, lead to mixed strings in your output. I guess you should make the logger a singletone.

@zdf Singletons are just glorified global variables and have all sorts of problems. I don't think advising anyone to use singletons is a good idea. It's IMHO a rather bad idea.

As written, the mutex synchronizes writing to the file, but not opening the file. The code tries to more or less simultaneously create 25 different steam objects, all pointing at the same file. That’s just not going to work; the OS won’t let you open a file that’s already open. Either use exactly one stream object and synchronize the writing, or synchronize creating the stream object, writing to it, and closing it.

@RemyLebeau Defining log_file_ as static also solved my problem. Previously I thought that an instance of a pending buffered I/O operation has the detail of the file offset where tha data will be written when flushed.  But from the comments I understand that a buffered operation means appending the data to the end of file for this example. Those flushes weren't under my control because I didn't flush writes while holding the lock.  And that resulted undefined behaviour. Right?

@JesperJuhl Okay I see that now. My code sample should be compiled as it is. Without adding a single line to it. I will keep that in mind for future posts.

@PeteBecker I see that I should use one stream object. But why doesn't OS let me to open an already opened file. As far as I know the OS permits opening a file that is already opened by another thread if I use the correct file sharing flags.

Yes, the OS has no problem opening a file multiple times, with the right flags. But C++ streams don't expose access to all available flags.

@RemyLebeau Ohh. I see. I analyzed the progam with ProcMon tool. Although based on logs the tool generated all CreateFile operations are successful and have Read, Write share flags for the stream objects. Also I saw that there are exactly 25 write operations but some of the write offsets are the same which results overlapping.

@JesperJuhl They are not inherently "bad". In the right context, singletons can offer a clean and practical solution.

In your example, every thread creates a new Logger instance. Each instance has its own stream, which means each instance also has its own internal buffer. You do not synchronize these buffers.
One solution is to use a single shared stream. While broken messages (e.g., "this is a te" followed by "this is a st") could occur in your example, this won't happen here because there is only one buffer. Note that depending on your platform and compiler, it might be necessary to define _DISABLE_CONSTEXPR_MUTEX_CONSTRUCTOR.
A possible implementation:
#include <fstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

class logger_t
{
public:
  static logger_t& instance()
  {
    static logger_t inst; // thread safe since c++11
    return inst;
  }

  void message(const std::string m)
  {
    std::lock_guard lock(mutex_);
    os_ << m;
  }

protected:
  logger_t() = default;
  ~logger_t() = default;

  std::mutex mutex_;
  std::ofstream os_{"c:/temp/log.txt", std::ios::app};
};

void f()
{
  logger_t::instance().message( "this is a test " );
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::thread> threads;

  for (int i = 0; i < 123; ++i)
    threads.emplace_back(f);

  for (auto& t : threads)
    t.join();
}

